# Make Single File RW on Read-Only Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

As part of a larger hardening effort, I am trying to make my container read-only, however, the application needs to edit the /etc/resolve.conf file. Historically I would just make the folder a tmpfs or bind mount depending on if the data was important, however, I would prefer to avoid making the entire /etc/ folder RWable. I am not entirely sure the proper approach for this problem and a mix of google and chatGPT hasn't given any real satisfactory answers.

```
services:
  protonwire:
    container_name: protonwire
    # Use semver tags or sha256 hashes of manifests.
    # using latest tag can lead to issues when used with
    # automatic image updaters like watchtower.
    build:
      context: ./ProtonWire
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    #image: ghcr.io/tprasadtp/protonwire:latest
    init: true
    # Restart the updater after reboot
    restart: unless-stopped
    # Make the container filesystem read-only
    read_only: true
```

Is there a supported docker native solution for this?
If not, what are some alternative strategies, I am coming up mostly empty handed.